# Why Rails developer use WordPress CMS for their blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

I dont know anything about Rails, but when searching about Rails Apps or coding, usually the developer use Wordpress CMS for their blog and not Rails

Is that because Rails prevent single user and not capable for creating a personal blog?

Answer (score 9):

Why would anyone want to reinvent the wheel? You don't need to build an entire app/framework for your blog and personal website, but Wordpress does everything you would want from a blog engine, the best part being the infinite theming possibilities. Plus, its extremely customizable if you want to include your own code.
Ruby on Rails otherwise is more than capable of building powerful web applications like blog engines.

Comment: Rails is perfectly capable of powering a blog site (there are many examples of this) but there is no need to reinvent the wheel when Wordpress does a great job.  Also, Wordpress sites are generally a lot cheaper to host.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also find developer blogs on Tumblr, Posterous (a rails app, I believe) and other free blogging services.  I would guess that there number of developers (Rails or otherwise) out there see any real benefit in writing their own blogging software when there are plenty of existing options out there to choose from, many of them good.

One noteable exception is https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll which takes a different, more lightweight approach to blogging software.  It's a Ruby app (not Rails) and I think I heard (or read) it referred to as blogging for hackers.  I know some developers use this too.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has been established for a long time and more people know about it. Hence, it is easier to find developers to work on your wordpress site vs a Rails site.

Rails is capable of creating a blog site as seen by numerous CMS such as Browser CMS, Radiant, etc. Also, https://github.com/fdv/typo created a very nicely done blogging engine for Rails which is in many ways comparable to Wordpress.

Anyway, Wordpress or Rails depends on what you are building, who you are building it for and who will manage it in the future. Hope this helps!

PS: It is much cheaper to hire a wordpress developer (PHP) on odesk vs Rails developer